# Vuejs - @click not triggering methods

Tags: vuejs2, onclick

I'm just tring to do simple onclick methods but I'm not sure why the methods are not triggered. 
 
My buttons:

```
<template>
    <div class="button">
          <a
            long
            class="cancel-button"
            @click="cancelOnClick"
          >Cancel</a>
          <a
            long
            class="ok-button"
            @click="okOnClick"
          >OK</a>
     </div>
</template>
```

My method:

```
export default {
  methods: {
      cancelOnClick(){  console.log('Cancel clicked')  }
      okOnClick()    {  console.log('OK     clicked')  }
  }
}
```

But when I change the

> @click="cancelOnClick"

to

> :click="this.cancelOnClick()"

then the function will keep triggered without clicking it. I'm not sure what's happening. Any help suggestions ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, your code seems to be working fine: https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/BayajVZ?editors=1111

Comment: It is possible that your css is preventing the click event, check if you have "no pointer events"

Answer (score 0):

`@click="cancelOnClick"` is working...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="test-template">
    <div class="button">
          <a
            long
            class="cancel-button"
            @click="cancelOnClick"
          >Cancel</a>
          <a
            long
            class="ok-button"
            @click="okOnClick"
          >OK</a>
     </div>
</script>
<div id="app"></div>
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#test-template',
  methods: {
      cancelOnClick(){  console.log('Cancel clicked')  },
      okOnClick()    {  console.log('OK     clicked')  }
  }
})
</script>
```